# Apply required field to referenced JSON data schema

Tags: json, reference, jsonschema

I have the following use-case I try to solve with JSON schemas.

I have a generic JSON data schema for, for example, a user. Here is an example of the user.schema.json file.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "locale": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "active": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 8
    },
    "roles": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have 2 different kinds of requests:
- POST: Add a user
- PATCH: Update user data.

In 1 case, I can send this data structure, with 3 required fields, while in case of a patch each field is optional.
So I get the post request file: post-user.schema.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$ref": "user.schema.json",
  "required": [
    "name",
    "password",
    "email"
  ]
}
```

And for my patch (path-user.schema.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$ref": "user.schema.json"
}
```

Now the issue that I am having is that my POST schema also marks a user like:

```
{
    "name": "NoPassword",
    "email": "nopassword@moba.nl",
    "roles": []
}
```

Which is missing the required password field, as a valid JSON schema.

Apparently, this is not the way to assign required fields to a referenced data structure. I have tried to use google to see what I can find on the subject regarding this using searches like:
[ how to assign required field to referenced schema's ]
and I tried to obtain this info from the documentation.

I have no luck.

My questions now are:
A. Is it possible to assign required fields to a $referenced json schema data object.
B. If this is possible how to do it
C. If this is not possible, what would be a good way to approach this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yup, you can do this, but you were probably not searching for the right phrases. I'll whip up an answer for you in the next few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$ref` results in all other properties in the object being ignored, so you need to wrap your use of `$ref`.

Let's take a look at the spec:

> An object schema with a "$ref" property MUST be interpreted as a
> "$ref" reference.  The value of the "$ref" property MUST be a URI
> Reference.  Resolved against the current URI base, it identifies the
> URI of a schema to use.  All other properties in a "$ref" object MUST
> be ignored.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-01#section-8.3

Then consider the schema you included in your question:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$ref": "user.schema.json",
  "required": [
    "name",
    "password",
    "email"
  ]
}
```

Reading the spec, you can see why `required` will be ignored.

Originally `$ref` was only designed to replace a WHOLE object, not ADD to the conditions for the object.

What you want is for multiple schemas to be applied to the instance. To do this, you use `allOf`.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "user.schema.json"
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "name",
        "password",
        "email"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I loaded this schema into a demo for you to test at [https://jsonschema.dev](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASMBjAFgUwLYCGqkKI2ALhQA6QD0dAVmAPbwC0WeRAdCwE4BzOgBN+hAGYV2ABgDsdLgUIBiVABoEyVIQA2ugPISSiANpbkiOEkvaQFAJ7VcJ1CwBGjXJgoaLt1BFcCQBLeBCKELYwE2AAX00bAPQlIldyKloGZjZOHGU+IVFxKVkFVNU-JMtUan4WZ35I3BioK39bMnhCfBc2607O1EdndLAKfjDBKsHk-DCAGVx4QQpsEwBGDtsE7ZqQZRDdWL3kkb7SVHHJlZnZu3n4JZW1zdPEXerk3RZMPQv2l8hvYnACrhMpnd7qhHs9Vus2lsgchPtCQIQfCEAG4Agb3MjndLuFgsXS4QjwKGzQLBQgAV10vjaEzpLmRH0SaOohDAYAA7gIRCd2XZCW1wTdpiBOfiYYtlvCTAAOd6o6kgepk1qkPFosWXdH8cQOKmDVARAjawH4-b6sjXSHS95zeUvBGkJE2uKqvbe6pq5C6-b8XAARzpIRDQra5nZqG6vVN+25vIF-GjMrNByIR1QewAuh0-chC-A4tKQCEoDBy3EgA) - although it doesn't support references yet, so I transcluded the reference, but the validation will work the same.

From draft-8 onwards, `$ref` will behave as you expect, as it becomes an applicator keyword rather than a keyword with special behaviours, meaning other keywords in the same object will not need to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.