# Why do we have to use pkg_resources or pkg_utils to read a static file inside the package?

Tags: python, python-import, jsonschema, cpython, python-importlib

```
schemas
├── common
│   ├── common1.json
│   └── common2.json
├── __init__.py
└── main.json
```

Why we have to use `pkg_resources` or `pkg_utils` to read a static file inside the python package?
I am asking this question because I am not able to reference the `common1.json` schema file from the `main.json` schema file.

here is the link for the initial head up on external file reference in JSON schema [Liquid Studio: How to write a JSON schema $ref to another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999230/liquid-studio-how-to-write-a-json-schema-ref-to-another-file).

here is the link to an issue I created on `jsonschema` package
https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/836.

Below is my analysis of the cause.

This is the function to `import` the module:

```
>>> def import_module(module_name):
...     source_path = module_name + '.py'
...     with open(source_path,"r") as module_file:
...             source_code = module_file.read()
...     mod = types.ModuleType(module_name)
...     mod.__file__ = source_path
...     code = compile(source_code,source_path,"exec")
...     exec(code, mod.__dict__)
...     return mod
...
```

Is it the same with `module_name` being `__init__.py` for package?

As python packages are also modules with an extra `__path__` attribute.
A file inside the python package should be importable and we need to follow the above sequence to import a module and in that sequence, there is a step where we need to create and execute the module which can be done for python files only.

Is `pkg_resourse` skipping the execution of the module?